# What happens when you try to save managedObjectContext from a different thread?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-data

So I know that NSManagedObjects are not thread safe and managedObjectIDs are, and we need a separate managedObjectContext per thread. But recently I had an issue when I was doing some core data changes in the background (had a separate runloop thread for this) and performSelectorOnThread: method sometimes was simply not invoked on this runloop thread. It turned out that the reason was that I was doing

```
    [someObject.managedObjectContext save:&error]
```

on this runloop thread and "someObject" was created on the main thread. But it would only "hung" runloop thread once in a while. So the question is what really happens if you try to save context in a different thread. I'm just looking for a deeper understanding, thanks.

Comment: Try to imagine all life as you know it stopping instantaneously, and every molecule in your body exploding at the speed of light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html :

> Core Data uses thread (or serialized queue) confinement to protect
>   managed objects and managed object contexts (see “Concurrency with
>   Core Data”). A consequence of this is that a context assumes the
>   default owner is the thread or queue that allocated it—this is
>   determined by the thread that calls its init method. You should not,
>   therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a
>   different thread. Instead, you should pass a reference to a persistent
>   store coordinator and have the receiving thread/queue create a new
>   context derived from that.

Answer (score 0):

You will crash. Maybe it will work sometimes and you won't see a crash while debugging, but you should never do this. Object contexts and the managed objects in them should only be used on the thread on which they were created. Apple's documentation is very clear about this and gives many examples of how to handle situations where you may have long running operations (slow fetches or async saves). You should read the docs that talk about threading with Core Data for more info.